# Visual Studio Apache Cordova - Windows Phone (Universal) Where is the appx?

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

where is the appx file after a succeeded windows phone (universal) build?

Regards Henry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll see them in platforms\windows\AppPackages. Just turn on show all files and build for Windows and you'll see them here:

[image]